# Android actionbar menu item

Tags: android, listview, visibility, menuitem

I have a item menu (sorting list) in my actionbar that I have to set its visibility to VISIBLE / GONE (depending on the list size -> empty or not).

So what I need is to check if listview is empty or not and set the visibility of that menu item accordingly, and I managed to came up with some code to do that (check listview size in onCreateOptionsMenu and set menu item visibility), but the problem is that the list can change its content both from same activity or from another, leaving me no option (IMO) than to check again listview size and set visiblity in onResume().

Here comes next problem: setting visibility of that item in onResume(), will throw a NPE, as I don't yet have that MenuItem initialized (onCreateOptionsMenu is called after onResume).
Any ideas on how to solve this situation would be appreciated.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    /*
     * initialize sortMenuItem so it can be used for turning visibility
     * on/off in onResume()
     */
    sortMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_sort);

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    boolean isListEmpty = mInterviewsList.isEmpty();

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "sortMenuItem is null? " + (sortMenuItem == null)); 
            // sortMenuItem is indeed null

    sortMenuItem.setVisible(isListEmpty);
    sortMenuItem.setEnabled(!isListEmpty);
    this.invalidateOptionsMenu();

}
```

Comment: I think wherever you are updating the content of listview using notifyDataSetChanged(), you can set the visibility of menu items there.Isn't it?

Comment: My problem is getting the sortMenuItem object initialized before actually modifying the listview, so it won't throw NPE anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add sortMenuItem dynamicaly in onCreateOptionsMenu depending on your listview size and in onResume call [supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) if you use (google ActionBar compat lib) or similar method.

Comment: This is what I`m actually doing (more or less). What I actually do, is inflating the sortMenu from xml, and call invalidateOptionsMenu, but it does not get there, because it stops at: sortMenuItem.setVisible(isListEmpty) in onCreate. (NPE)

Comment: I've modified it accordingly to your answer too, with same result.

Comment: It is in an Activity.

Comment: "sortMenuItem.setVisible(isListEmpty) in onCreate" sure, because onCreateOptionsMenu was not called. In your case in onResume you should call `this.invalidateOptionsMenu();` at first and after that `sortMenuItem.setVisible(isListEmpty);` etc